# Solve a partial differential equation knowing a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> Solve $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=c^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x \partial x}$ assuming we know the solutions of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x \partial x}$

I don't know much about pde's. I've been reading about it but I'm not sure if I get it.

I think I could start changing slightly the form to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-c^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x \partial x}=0$. What I've read is about equations of the form $au_{xx}+bu_{xy}+cu_{yy}=0$.

Here I would like to use $\Delta=c^2-4(1)(0)=c^2.$ and then ince $\Delta >0$ it should be a hyperbolic solution: $u$ has the form $u=f(mx+y)$.

But does this makes sense? The first partial derivate with respect to $t$ bothers me, and it seems it what I wanted to do won't work here since I want $u_t=c^2u_{xx}$.

EDIT:

$v=u(a,b)$

With $a(x,t)=x/c, b(t)=t.$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\displaystyle\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}+\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial b}\displaystyle\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}$

Since $\displaystyle\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}=0, \displaystyle\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}=1$ then
$\displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial b}=\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$

And 
$\displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\displaystyle\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}+\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial b}\displaystyle\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}$

since $\displaystyle\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} = 1/c$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}= 0$ it is $\displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} =\displaystyle\frac{1}{c}\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial (x/c)}$

Comment: Apply the chain rule for $v(x, t)=u(x/c, t)$. What is $v_t$? And $v_{xx}$?

Comment: @N74 I'm sorry, but I'm quite confused. The partial derivatives seem to be the same.

Comment: You have $v(x,t)=u(z,t)$ where $z=x/c$. So $v_x=u_z{dz \over dx}=u_z/c=u_x(x/c,t)/c$. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Does the last line read $\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{ c}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x/c,t)$?

Comment: @Cure If you already know the solution for your old PDE $u_{t} = u_{xx}$, then it makes sense to convert your new PDE $u_{t} = c^{2}u_{xx}$ to your old PDE by scaling your variables so you can easily obtain the solution to your new PDE. In order to do so, you just want to eliminate the $c^{2}$ term from your new PDE. It is probably easier to just map $u(x,t) = v(x, c^{2}t)$ so that $u_{t} = c^{2} v_{t}$ and the new PDE becomes $v_{t} = v_{xx}$.